# Types and elementary extensions

Tags: model-theory

Let $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ be two $\mathcal{L}$-structures and suppose that for n-tupls $\bar{a}\in M^n$ and $\bar{b}\in N^n$, 
$tp^\mathcal{M}(\bar{a})=tp^\mathcal{N}(\bar{b})$ where $tp^\mathcal{M}(\bar{a})=\{\varphi: 
\mathcal{M}\models\varphi(\bar{a})\}$. Is it true that:

There is an $\mathcal{}L$-structure 
$\mathcal{A}$ and elementary embeddings $f:\mathcal{M}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{A}$ and 
$g:\mathcal{N}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{A}$ such that $f(a_i)=g(b_i)$ for $1\le i\le n$.

or there is a Counterexample?

Comment: Show us your thoughts and what you have tried by editing the question, so that people are willing to help you.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $(\mathcal M, \overline a)$ and $(\mathcal N, \overline b)$ are elementarily equivalent. This is just saying that $tp^{\mathcal M}(\overline a)=tp^{\mathcal N}(\overline b)$, in a different way. There is a standard proposition that then allows you to conclude.